# Suppose a static method were to invoke a non-static method directly. How would the method know which object’s instance variables to manipulate?

Tags: c#

Please help me I don't understand this, because when I invoke a method from a non- static class I used the Object i.e: let's say the name of the class is Time, using this would be:

Console.WriteLine(time.myMethod()); //or some custom Static method with doesn't                    //return a string PS. I am aware it should be a string

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you're asking here. "Suppose something impossible were possible - how would that work?" isn't a good starting point.

Comment: Proper way of writing static methods is NOT to depend on a instance's attributes. And the static method DOES NEVER know anything about any object as long as thos object  is NOT passed in as argument durin the call.
Utility classes  for example, take sometimes "out" or "ref" typed arguments, making it possible to be changed by the static method.

Comment: @icbytes, and anyone using `out` or `ref` with static methods should be shot foe gross crimes against software.

Comment: What about the Math class ? And other static classes offering this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. If you try this, you will get a compile error, precisely because of the reasons you describe.

Short example:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Inner.getText();
    }

    class Inner {
        string GetText() {
            return "text";
        }
    }
}
```

This will not compile because of:

> 'Program.Inner' does not contain a definition for 'getText'

Comment: But does that definitely cover OP's question ? He did not state : Inner classes.

Comment: It would work (well: NOT work of course) the same way with normal classes.

Comment: But the static is missing in Your final argumentation.

Comment: Thank you it can be a bit confusing at times